# CDE-Solaris GTK3 Theme

Tags: themes, solaris, gtk

I've tested and tried many GTK+ Themes, but found the one that ease on the eyes the ***most*** is still the oldest CDE-Solaris Theme:

[image: CDE-Solaris Theme]

I believe this color combination has been carefully engineered exactly for the purpose to make people ***comfortable*** staring at the monitor for a *prolonged time*, and apparently more people agree with that:

> This is definitely one of the best themes around.

However the [CDE-Solaris Theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php/CDE-Solaris?content=19627) I am able to find is only available in GTK2.

Anyone knows if a GTK3 version is available somewhere? If not, is there any GTK3 Theme that is close to such color combination? (I'm not interested in the shinny bell&whistles that comes with the theme, but its color combination instead). Thx.

Comment: I'm still looking for `olvwm` for Solaris 11. What do you need CDE's eye candy and massively intrusive menus and icon bars for?  :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, no actually, I don't like those eye candy and massively intrusive menus and icon bars either. The only thing I like is the *color combination*, which makes my eyes comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [HP-UXMotif](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013518/) theme:

[image]

as well as [Belle Pintos Grande](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1173216/):

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, that "_Belle Pintos Grande_" looks really beautify. Finally something that I can make use out of the box without tweaking. THX!

Comment: @xpt There’s also the real [CDE theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1231025/).

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I've seen so far are the Mist themes, except for the purpleness. But maybe there's a version like this.

But the gtk3 version I've found somewhere is kind of buggy, I had to blend it with Albatross' assets (pngs for checkboxes) and some css, otherwise some checkboxes wouldn't appear unless ticked.

Bluecurve and onestepback perhaps are worth a look:

https://www.gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=170904

But neither of those have these colors. Unfortunately gtk theming is messy as hell and doesn't even separate colors from themes.

Comment: I agree with every bit of what you are saying, especially that "_gtk theming is messy as hell_". Thx, and welcome aboard BTW, with my +25.

Comment: +1 for _gtk theming is messy as hell_

Answer (score 0):

> The only thing I like is the color combination, which makes my eyes comfortable

Just use this tool https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1013373/ and pick the colors from your screenshot :-)

Comment: Good tool, but, "_the command 'bash gnomecc2gtk3css.sh' will convert config.xml to config.css - the file config.xml is updated everytime the Apply button from gnome-color-chooser is clicked..._", Nah, too much hassle to use.

Comment: I believe you first use gnome-color-chooser and any gtk2 program to see the end result, and only at the end you run converter to create gtk3 theme from it.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.